# ExactTarget - JSON Feed as source

Tags: json, salesforce, exacttarget, ampscript

Having a tough time with ExactTarget's documentation. The example below from their docs works just fine, but I'm having trouble setting the var Json to an actual JSON feed. What am I missing?

```
 %%[ var @Json set @Json = ' [{"emailaddress":"john@example.com","Region":"West","State":"California","City":"San Francisco"},
 {"emailaddress":"carla@example.com","Region":"Central","State":"Indiana","City":"Indianapolis"}]' ]%%

 {{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 20}}
    {{.data}}
    { "target" : "@Json" }
    {{/data}}
    Email Address: {{emailaddress}}
    Region: {{region}}
    State: {{STATE}}
    City: {{JSONVar.City}}
 {{/datasource}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using Server-Side Javascript?  Ampscript does not contain a function for parsing JSON.  However, SSJS does.

Also for future reference, consider posting you questions at salesforce.stackexchange.com under the tag Marketing-Cloud.

**reference:**

- **AMPScript functions:**  http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_functions/
- **SSJS online help:**  http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/

Comment: After some more research, SSJS seems to be the answer. Thanks.